# .gitignore not working as intended

Tags: git

I have 3 things in my .gitignore:

```
node_modules/
credentials.js
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

The issue is that, whenever I make changes to `credentials.js`, I am still able to commit that file when I opened up my Sourcetree.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `git rm --cached credentials.js`.

Comment: To expound upon the above comment, if you haven't yet removed `credentials.js` from being tracked by the repository, then its presence in `.gitignore` won't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In contrast to what the name "ignore" might suggest. `.gitignore` is only consulted when you `git add` files: in other words a file already added to the (index of the) repository will not be excluded based on the `.gitignore`.

First you better modify the .gitignore such that the file is no longer added. Add the following line to the `.gitignore` file:

```
public/app/credentials.js
```

Next you need to exclude the file from the repository. Probably you don't want to remove the file from your file system, this can be done with:

```
git rm --cached public/app/credentials.js
```

The `--cached` flag ensures the file will not be removed from your file system. (If not important, you can use git rm public/app/credentials.js, but this will remove the file).

Comment: so what if the next time I would like to edit credentials.js and commit the file ?

Comment: Then you can remove the credentials.js file from .gitignore.After that add the file and commit.

Comment: can you try to answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190478/how-to-gitignore-some-files-between-the-2-applications-in-herokuapp ?